# Angular2/4/6 Pass Custom Pipe Filtered List from HTML to Component

Tags: angular, pipe, hidden-field

I'm currently working on a search bar component. Using custom pipe, I'm able to show a dropdown list of items. I need to pass the filtered list of items (Items | CustomPipe : search_input) from searchbar.component.html to searchbar.component.ts but I'm not sure how

**searchbar.component.html**

```
<ul *ngIf="(Items | CustomPipe : search_input).length>0" class="list-group dropdown-container">
    <li *ngFor="let item of Items | CustomPipe : search_input; index as i" [class.active]="i == arrowkeyLocation" (mouseover)=changeStyle($event)
        (mouseleave)=changeStyle($event) (click)="showConfirm(item)" class="list-group-item" [innerHTML]="item.model | highlight : search_input"></li>
</ul>
```

My current approach:

```
<input #filterSize type="hidden" value="{{(Items | CustomPipe : search_input).length}}">
<input #filterContent type="hidden" value="{{(Items | CustomPipe : search_input)}}">
```

**searchbar.component.ts**

```
export class SearchbarComponent implements OnInit {
 arrowkeyLocation: number = 0;
@ViewChild('filterSize') filterSize: any;
@ViewChild('filterContent') filterContent: any;
@Output() onSelect: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
constructor() {
}
ngOnInit() { }
changeStyle(event) {

    let content = this.filterContent.nativeElement.value;
    let dropdownSize = this.filterSize.nativeElement.value;

    if (event.type == "keydown") {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 38: // this is the ascii of arrow up
                if (this.arrowkeyLocation == -1) {
                    this.arrowkeyLocation = dropdownSize;
                }
                this.arrowkeyLocation--;
                break;
            case 40: // this is the ascii of arrow down
                if (this.arrowkeyLocation == dropdownSize) {
                    this.arrowkeyLocation = -1;
                }
                this.arrowkeyLocation++;
                break;
            case 13:
                this.onSelect.emit(content[this.arrowkeyLocation]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm not able to retrieve the list of objects correctly (content variable). It's passed over from html to the component as a string value of [object Object]. Anyone can suggest a workaround this?

Comment: hi pixelbits, sorry to cause a confusion, I've rephrased my question. Nothing wrong with my custom pipe. it's just I want to implement a key press event for the search bar so that when the user presses enter it goes to the correct location. For that to happen I need to retrieve the filtered list of dropdown items from the html so I can use it in my changeStyle method in the component but I don't know how

Comment: why do you use your custom pipe on the list and on the input tag? is there a reason ? and you have some typos there with mouseover and mouseleave attributes, you're missing "".  Please try to provide a https://stackblitz.com/ example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide a work-around for this.

1. Use a normal utility function and in that function implement the filter logic.
2. on keypress event call that function from **searchbar.component.ts** and populate 
   **filtered content**
3. Then use **filtered content** in **searchbar.component.ts** as you wish
4. Also Use **filtered content** in your **searchbar.component.html** as well.

**Example:** *[This is not a real code]*

**searchbar.component.ts**

```
KeyPressCallback(search_input) {
    this.filteredContent = utilityFunctionToFilter(Items, search_input);
    // Do whatever you like with filteredContent.

}
```

**searchbar.component.html**

```
 <ul *ngIf="filteredContent.length>0" class="lis ...
```